# Epub - what are the keywords indicating text in html files

Tags: android, epub, epublib

I search for text of the book, not the title or author.

I have several epub files, but all have different keywords in the html files, preceding the text.

Do you have some information for what I should be looking for? or some good document?

Is it:

```
</head>
<body>
```

I've included some examples below:

Example 1: text starting with "To the man who loves...."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for FreeBSD (vers 7 December 2008), see www.w3.org" />
<title>The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
"application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
<div class="text">
<p>"To the man who loves art for its own sake," remarked Sherlock
Holmes, tossing aside the advertisement sheet of the Daily
Telegraph,
```

Example 2: text starting with "D’habitude, Éric n’aimait pas être dérangé..."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?--><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">
 <head> 
  <link href="../Styles/UPstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
  <title>La Voisine</title> 
  <style type="text/css">
div.sgc-3 {text-align:center}
</style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <p><br/></p> 
  <p>D’habitude, Éric n’aimait pas être dérangé. On aurait pu lui objecter que mettre de l’inattendu dans sa vie, en cette période de désœuvrement, pouvait s’avérer intéressant, mais Éric Aubray, paradoxalement, ne détestait pas s’ennuyer. L’ennui procurait un certain confort. L’absence d’illusions également. Allongé sur son divan de cuir râpé, aspirant voluptueusement la fumée d’une cigarette qui le tuerait à petit feu dans un laps de temps qui l’indifférait, il s’irrita donc du remue-ménage qui éclatait sur son palier. L’appartement d’en face, un meublé, était inoccupé depuis des mois. Ça l’arrangeait plutôt. Ce bruit de caisses tirées, de raclement de valises et de piétinements indiquait de possibles emmerdes à venir. Or il en avait eu son lot, ces derniers temps. Un licenciement sec (il y en avait rarement d’humide…), un divorce, et un compte en banque qui frôlait le zéro absolu (cela allait souvent de pair avec les deux précédents événements) – que demandait le peuple ? Qu’on lui foute la paix.</p> 
  <p>Or cette paix risquait d’être menacée par un voisin importun. Éric n’éprouvait nulle envie de se confier. Ni à un voisin, ni à un psy, encore moins à sa mère dépressive ou à son meilleur ex-ami, Maxence, qui conservait sans vergogne son poste de bibliothécaire en chef, le poste de bibliothécaire adjoint – celui d’Éric  – venant d’être supprimé pour cause de crise mondiale en général, et de compression du personnel de la ville – à un niveau plus local.</p> 
  <p>Éric regrettait l’ambiance feutrée de cette petite bibliothèque de quartier, fréquentée surtout par des étudiants et des retraités. L’odeur de papier, les lampes protégées par des abat-jour d’opaline, les chuchotements des habitués… Tout cela le rassurait. La moquette était usée jusqu’à la corde, les rayonnages auraient eu besoin d’un ravalement, mais les bruits de la ville, dans ce lieu, parvenaient à peine, étouffés par les doubles-vitrages. Un petit kiosque, aux arbres un peu malingres, tentait de susciter, au printemps, une certaine illusion de campagne. Même si, tout compte fait, l’attirance du jeune homme pour la chlorophylle restait toute virtuelle.</p> 
  <p>Dans son appartement,
```

Comment: In the 2 examples you have shown, all the relevant text is contained in the `<p/>` tags (excluding the title).

Comment: easy! do you know a good and simple doc describing the other keywords? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a reference  about (D)HTML? Google for that - you'll find a godzillion. A much accredited free learning site is the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks!